# Make microcontroller connect to OS X as mouse

Tags: macos, mouse, driver, hardware, microcontroller

I have just begun a new project. I'd like to make my own simplistic computer mouse, since i'd like to learn how to program hardwear drivers and understand the protocols the hardwear uses. I have experience in both desktop and microcontroller programming. However, I haven't got a clue about how to write drivers. I'm working on a mac with OS X and the mouse only needs to be able to talk with OS X. I expect to use a MSP430 microcontroller from TI. I intend to connect my mouse via USB. I simply want to be directed in the right direction not specific help with the coding, yet. :)

I therefor have a couple of questions:

1. Should I write my own driver or is it possible to use a standard one?
   If yes, what kind of driver should be written and where do you begin?
2. What kind of data should be sent to the mac to say, "Hey, I'm a computer mouse"?
3. Which protocols should I read about?

Answer (score 0):

You can check USB HID articles for OSX side and if there exists for MSP430.

I think that you can use any other driver, if you emulate same behavior of the target device on your MSP side.